# Dynamic string array without using vector

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I am working on an assignment where we have to create a "student" object with a "course" member array that is dynamic so the user can enter from one course to as many as they'd like in the array. I've been trying this every which way and just cannot get the array to resize and accept new elements. Here is my code as it stands now:

```
cout << "Enter student name > ";
cin >> name;

Student firstStudent(name);

cout << endl << "Enter \"done\" when you are complete";
cout << endl << "Enter a new course : ";
cin >> course;

while (course != "done") {
    numCourses++;
    firstStudent.addElement(numCourses, course);//makes the array bigger
    cout << endl << "Enter a new course : ";
    cin >> course;

}//end while
```

member variables and constructor:

```
class Student
{
private:
   string name;//name of student

   string *dynArray = new string[1];//array

public:
Student::Student(string name)
{
   this->name = name;
   this->numC = 1;//initialized to one to start with    
}
```

resizing and adding an element to the array:

```
void Student::addElement(int numCourses, string &course) {//DYNAMIC ARRAY
    if (numCourses > this->numC) {//checks if there are more courses than there is room in the array
       this->numC = numCourses; //this changes the member variable amount
       dynArray[numCourses] = course;//adds new course to array

       string *temp = new string[numC];//create bigger temp array

       temp = dynArray;//write original to temp

       delete[]dynArray; //this tells it that it's an array

       dynArray = temp;//make dynarray point to temp

    }
    else {
       dynArray[numCourses] = course;//adds new course to array
    }
}//end addElement
```

Even if I manage to get rid of compile errors, it will often come up with runtime errors. I'm sure it has to do with pointers/copying arrays but I'm just learning and haven't yet mastered these concepts.

Edit: dynArray[numCourses] = course; creates a char array. ie if course = "one", dynArray[0] = "o", dynArray[ 1] = "n", etc. Does anyone know how to keep this from happening?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5gRH.png)

Comment: You can't copy arrays with the assignment `temp = dynArray`. You have to write a loop that copies each element of the array.

Comment: Where you declare `numC`?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I had tried that one at one point. I was grasping at straws with the assignment, haha. It seems that the problem i'm having is namely at the dynArray[numCourses] = course; part; adding even the first course into the array isn't happening. I might be missing something because I'm pretty tired and sick of this dumb thing :P

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский numC is declared as 1 in the default constructor of Student

Comment: You should do `numCourses++` **after** you insert the element, not before. Otherwise you'll skip the first element of the array.

Comment: @Barmar there is an else statement in addElement that should account for it. The first course is going in now, however when I examine it, it looks like an element ie "math" goes in as dynArray[0] = "m", dynArray[1] = "a", etc. any idea why that'd be happening

Comment: What is the initial value of `numCourses` before the `while` loop? I assumed it starts as `0`, so the first `numCourses++` will set it to `1`, and the first course will be put into `dynArray[1]` instead of `dynArray[0]`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::vector<std::string>` for your `dynArray`?

Comment: @NeilKirk not allowed for this assignment, unfortunately.

Comment: @NeilKirk that would mean writing good code, which is not allowed in school

Comment: @Neil Because she's not allowed to use `vector` -- it says so in the title. It's an assignment to learn how to implement dynamic data structures.

Comment: @M.M It's not a matter of good versus bad. You need to learn these kinds of things -- someone has to be able to implement classes like `std::vector`.

Comment: If `std::vector` is not available (to make you  learn how it works under the hood) then the correct thing to do is implement your own vector-type class, and use that, rather than mixing the logic of how to handle a resizable array alongside other unrelated pieces of code.

Comment: @Barmar Implementing data structures is harder than using them. Beginner classes at school often require students to do both, and do not teach either well.

Comment: Implementing data structures teaches important **concepts**. I can't vouch for how well any particular class does this (if I'm to believe many of the questions here, it seems like students are frequently given assignments that require knowledge that was never taught, but I'll bet it's more often that the students were asleep during the lecture).

Comment: I posted an edit- it looks like the course isn't going into the first element correctly... any ideas?

Comment: @Barmar Do not underestimate the poor quality of teaching of programming in academia.

Answer (score 1):

The first line that that doesn't look quite correct is this one:

```
dynArray[numCourses] = course;
```

Before it is checked that `numCurses > numC`, which means that `dynArray[numCourses]` accesses memory out of bounds (the bounds are `0` to `numC - 1`.

The other thing that strikes me as interesting is that the `addElement` method takes `numCourses` as an argument. I would expect that it should behave similar to `std::vector<T>::push_back`. Are you sure this argument is necessary?

The last thing I want to comment on is that the values from `dynArray` are not copied. Have a look at `std::copy_n` on how to do the copy.

Comment: Actually, one last thing: I would expect that you start off with an empty array. Starting with `string[1]` is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: I had started with a one element array because I knew I needed one element at least anyway and to make sure that it was at least accepting a string as an element even if it isn't resizing. I'll make sure to change it when I get everything working. As for numCourses, that's a number that is increased every time an element is added which is how I base the size of the array. I'm not sure anymore why it is passed as an argument but I had a reason... at one point XD Does it pose a problem or just pointless?

Comment: Consider this code: `s.addElement(0, "a"); s.addElement(2, "b");` What is the value of the second element?

Comment: Ahhhh, I see what you mean. rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be considered cheating, but here's a break down of how std::vector is implemented. You could use that as a reference and just pick out the parts you need.

http://codefreakr.com/how-is-c-stl-implemented-internally/

Comment: I think it's not cheating so long as I understand the code and can implement it in the future :) thanks!